# Immediate selection of same slice of google pie chart not recognised

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, pie-chart

I am trying to display a modal with certain infomation when a particular slice of google pie chart is selected. The code is working fine when different slices are selected one after another but event is not being fired when same slice is selected for consecutively for the 2nd time.

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', selectHandler);
function selectHandler()
                    {
                        var selectedItem = chart.getSelection()[0];
                        if (selectedItem)
                        {
                            alert("here");
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the event *is* fired but the second time a slice is clicked, it is **un**-selected.

you should check the length of the selection before trying to access --> `[0]`

see following example...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
      ['Work',     12],
      ['Eat',       2],
      ['Drink',     1],
      ['Commute',   1],
      ['Surf',      1],
      ['Watch TV',  1],
      ['Sleep',     6]
    ]);

    var pieChart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
    google.visualization.events.addListener(pieChart, 'select', function () {
      document.getElementById('selection').innerHTML = 'Items selected: ' + pieChart.getSelection().length;
    });
    pieChart.draw(data, {});
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="piechart"></div>
<div id="selection"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you ! this explanation really helped :)